# Synchronize a timer with textclock refresh in AwesomeWM

Tags: timer, awesome-wm

I try to synchronize a cairo surface's update with my `textclock` refresh.

Is it possible to hook a `gears.timer` to `textclock`'s one? or should I create a `textbox` and use the same `gears.timer` to update both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, not without using private APIs, which is not recommended (`mytextclock._timer`).

However, a better alternative is to create a timer, then create your own textclock using a `wibox.widget.textbox` when it timeouts. It can be done in 1 line using [`os.date`](https://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html)